# What is the best way to push a user to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 1.6.2.

I have a function in a page that needs to direct the user to another page within the site and pass some variables along with it.

The function will post some data, then retrieve some data and then make a decision on where to take the user next.

Is this the best way to move someone to a specific page?

Is this the best way to code this piece?

```
QueryString = "?ArtistID=" + ArtistID;
window.location = 'MyNewPage.cfm' + QueryString
```

What other options are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be modifying href (and i would inline the pointless global variable )

```
window.location.href = 'MyNewPage.cfm?ArtistID=" + ArtistID;
```

Comment: If the following line is the only use of that variable, then it's being instantiated for no benefit, because you're concatenating strings together either way. Of course if you use QueryString for other purposes later on, that's entirely different.

Comment: What RET said. also, if you don't put a var in front of a variable in js, you are making a global, which is usually not what you want..

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. The code I put on SO isn't the actual code I would cut and paste into my page. Yes, I might pass three or four variables in a string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generally valid and accepted way to change location.

A few other ways could also work:

```
location.href = str;
location.assign(str);
location.replace(str); //Doesn't create new entry in the back button history
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I like the benefit of reducing back button messes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following property

```
document.location.href = theUrl;
```